# ShingleFilter is not working for maxShingleSize=3

Tags: filter, solr, shingles

Enviornment ==> solr - solr-8.9.0, java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS

Following .csv file is indexed in solr

```
books_id,cat,name
0553573403,book,Game Thrones Clash
0553573404,book,GameThrones Clash
0553573405,book,GameThronesClash
0553573406,book,GameThronesClas
```

Schema defined in managed-schema as follows

```
<field name="books_id" type="plong" multiValued="false" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="cat" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="3"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I expect that if i query the book 'GameThronesClash', it should give me other three books. so shingleFilterFactory has been
configurd with  minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="3".

I understand that construct shingles from token stream.

```
In: "Game Thrones Clash"

Tokenizer to Filter: "Game"(1), "Thrones"(2), "Clash"(3)

Out: "Game"(1), "GameThrones"(1), "GameThronesClash"(1), "Thrones"(2), "ThronesClash"(2),"Clash"(3)
```

But following query

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/shingleConcatenationFuzzyCore/select --data-urlencode "q=(name:'GameThronesClash~')"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":15,
    "params":{
      "q":"(name:'GameThronesClash~')"}},
  "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "books_id":0553573404,
        "cat":"book",
        "name":"GameThrones Clash",
        "id":"22674fc1-9fc7-4e1b-8d09-231acf39bc25",
        "_version_":1743512855396745216},
      {
        "books_id":0553573405,
        "cat":"book",
        "name":"GamethronesClash",
        "id":"e82a0dee-a3fb-483e-806b-e667490536f4",
        "_version_":1743512855375773696},
      {
        "books_id":0553573406,
        "cat":"book",
        "name":"GameThronesclas",
        "id":"bf240788-81cd-4a51-b62d-5aba778e1dee",
        "_version_":1743512855376822272}
  }}
```

But why is not giving books having Id : "books_id":0553573403,("name":"Game Thrones Clash").
What to change in the query to
retrieve book having name as "name":"Game Thrones Clash"

"Analysis" page under Solr's Admin page for specific field 'name' is as mentioned below -

Field value (Index) :==>name:'Game Thrones Clash'
[image: WithoutConcatenation(Index)]

Field value (Index) :==>name:'GameThronesClash'
[image: Concatenated(index)]

Field value (Query) :==>name:'Game Thrones Clash'
[image]

Field value (Query) :==>name:'GameThronesClash'
[image]

Comment: You can use the "Analysis" page under Solr's Admin page for that specific field to see exactly how both the index analysis chain processes your content and how the query gets processed.

Comment: @MatsLindh...Thankx for reply! I had checked in the 'Analysis' page. It was giving me all in "SF' of type 'shingle'... Game, Game Thrones, Game Thrones Clash, Thrones, Thrones Clash, Clash.. As it should be for "Field value(Index)" : "name:"Game Thrones Clash~".... But query is not giving output, if it is concatenated : "GameThronesClash"., Infact it is giving output books_id 0553573404 (GameThrones Clash), but not books_id : 0553573403(Game Thrones Clash):... Why is it so?

Comment: Is that expected behavior or what I did do wrong?...I want output as 'Games Thrones Clash' for input as 'GamesThronesClash'...and both documents are indexed in solr.

Comment: If you include the analysis output it'll be far easier to say something - it's hard to parse details in the comments. You might also want to test without `~` in the query, so that it doesn't confuse issues.

Comment: @MatsLindh...Thankx for reply! I have added index analysis and query section in the question. kindly see.

Comment: First: you only want the term present, not the query itself (so drop the `name` part - as you can see, it's considered part of the token). But further - if you look at the tokens generated, they're `game thrones clash`, not `gamethronesclash` as you said they'd be. This will depend on which separator char you have defined for your shingle filter (in your case, you haven't defined a separator, so the default is ` ` - a space, not an empty string). You can change this by using `tokenSeparator=""` on the shingle filter definition. This may or may not be what you want considering other tokens.